# Why is the time in my Python programm not updating?

Tags: python

I want to display time in a python programm. When I start the programm it gets the time but than it dont changes.
Here is my code:

```py
import time
import pytz
from datetime import datetime

current_time = datetime.now(pytz.timezone('Europe/Madrid')).strftime("%H:%M:%S")

while True:
    print(current_time)
    time.sleep(5)
```

I always get the same time and i have no idea why

Comment: Because `current_time` is the same variable with same value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not updating the time in your programm.

`datetime.now` result is stored only once in a variable `current_time`.

If you want to get the current time at each loop iteration :

```py
import time
import pytz
from datetime import datetime

while True:
  #update the time here
  current_time = datetime.now(pytz.timezone('Europe/Madrid')).strftime("%H:%M:%S")
  print(current_time)
  time.sleep(5)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are assigning the `current_time` variable only once outside of the loop - you're displaying `current_time` every 5 seconds but you need to update the time every 5 seconds too.

To fix this, move the variable assignment inside the loop.

```
import time
import pytz
from datetime import datetime

while True:
    current_time = datetime.now(pytz.timezone('Europe/Madrid')).strftime("%H:%M:%S")
    print(current_time)
    time.sleep(5)
```